# Replace a jQuery object path part with variable

Tags: jquery

I'm using objects in jQuery to store ad hoc data:

```
var objectFields = {
    venues: {
        type: "select",
        options: {
            objects: function() {
                var elementsObject = $("dl.list-venues").find("select");
                var elementsObjectNames = [];
                for (var i=0;i<elementsObject.length;i++) {
                    elementsObjectNames[i] = $(elementsObject[i]).attr("name");
                }
                return elementsObjectNames;
            },
            select: 1
        },
        errorMessage: "You need to select either a Venue or Venue Group"
    },...
```

Presently, I can access "errorMessage" via:

```
console.log(objectFields.venues.errorMessage);
```

But I also need to access it by replacing a path element with a variable:

```
console.log(objectFields.aVariableName.errorMessage);
```

However, having tried this method, in addition to many others, I've had zero success.

Any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: `objectFields[aVariableName].errorMessage`

Comment: @zzzzBov I've tried that and it gives an error.

Comment: Then you need to read the error message to find out what the other issue was. Are you sure `aVariableName` had the correct value when you called it?

Comment: @zzzzBov the brackets are the cause of the error: "SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '[' instead"

Comment: [Maybe you should post a fiddle, because you must be having some other problem](http://jsfiddle.net/2YcHb/).

Comment: @WayneSmallman - "SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '[' instead" - remove the `.`  It's not `objectFields.[aVariableName]`

Comment: @Archer yes, it was that. I had tried it, but I looked at the wrong log file.

Comment: So what error do you get when you do it correctly, or does it work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets

```
objectFields[aVariableName].errorMessage;
```

Comment: @LeeMeador I removed them; I only added them for emphasis, but it always confuses people, just like it has you.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery prototype, you can do this:

```
$(objectFields).attr('venues').errorMessage;
```

So just replace 'venues' with your attribute variable name, like this:

```
$(objectFields).attr(aVariableName).errorMessage;
```